# C# AspNetCore SignalR Client - Connection Closed Handler

Tags: c#, signalr, task, asp.net-core-signalr

AspNetCore SignalR client uses an async method for the closed handler like so.

```
HubConnection.Closed += async (exception) =>
{
    await SomeAwaitableTask();
};
```

But I don't have any task to complete when the connection is closed. I am going to just show a "Disconnected from Server" message with a button to restart the app so do not need nor have an aynsc awaitable Task for the Closed method.

I can get round this by using `Task.Delay(0)` in the method to complete its awaitable Task requirement like so.

```
HubConnection.Closed += async (exception) =>
{
    await Task.Delay(0);
    //Show message()
};
```

But it feels a rather hacky way to get round it, Is this as bad of a solution as it feels or is it the standard solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a `CompletedTask` without starting any asynchronous code.

```
HubConnection.Closed += (exception) =>
{
    // Show message()
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

Comment: An error is thrown if using `return` `Async lambda expression converted to a 'Task' returning delegate cannot return a value.` but `Task.CompletedTask` using `await` is ok

Comment: The lambda I have shown above is not `async`. This is a synchronous delegate returning a Task at the end which essentially avoids the overhead of using `async/await`

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice